# Using abstract class as parameter in base class constructor to have more specific types in derived classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Coming from data science I'm trying to learn oop for software development using c#.

I am trying to set up a base class (e.g. Aliments) from which a few other even more specific custom lists classes are going to derive (e.g. Fruits and Vegs). On the side I have individual Fruit and and Veg classes that derive from Aliment. In the end I want instances of Fruits/Vegs to have a List of Veg/Fruit propriety (along with a few proprieties and methods specific to the Fruits and Vegs classes). But I want this list propriety to be implemented in the Aliments base class along with a few methods to manage it (for instance RemoveRipe(), SortBySize()...)

I tried to put a List propriety in the Aliments class and then make the derived classes (Fuits/Vegs) call the base constructor with a List<Fruit> or List<Veg>.

I tried something like this:

```
public abstract class Aliment
{
    public int Ripeness;
}

public class Fruit : Aliment
{
    // be a fruit
}

public abstract class Aliments
{
    public Aliments(List<Aliment> alimentList)
    {
        AlimentList = alimentList;
    }

    public List<Aliment> AlimentList { get; private set; }

    public void RemoveRipe()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class Fruits : Aliments
{
    public Fruits(List<Fruit> fruitList)
        : base(fruitList)
    {

    }
}
```

The main problem is that the list of fruit cannot be converted to a list of aliments. Furthermore, the whole point of the operation is that each instance of Fruits has a List of actual Fruit (so that I can access the specific methods of Fruit). Is there any way I can do that ? Am I on a good way ?
Thanks in advance

P.S. Sorry if it is a duplicate I didn't really how to formulate the problem so as to search for it

Comment: It may make sense for a specific fruit to inherit from aliment (which I had to look up and one day will use in a sentence.) But do you need a collection of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say that we can't convert a `List<Fruit>` into a `List<Aliment>`, a lot depends on what we mean by "convert."

If you have a `List<Fruit>` and you want a `List<Ailment>`, you can accomplish that by creating a new list. For example, if `fruitList` is a `List<Fruit>`:

```
var alimentList = new List<Aliment>(fruitList.Cast<Aliment>())
```

Because every `Fruit` *is* an `Aliment`, you can cast each one of them as an `Aliment` and use them to populate a new `List<Aliment>`.

If you did that, your `Fruits` constructor would compile:

```
public class Fruits : Aliments
{
    public Fruits(List<Fruit> fruitList)
        : base(new List<Aliment>(fruitList.Cast<Aliment>()))
    { }
}
```

What we can't do is *cast* a `List<Fruit>` as a `List<Aliment>`.

Why? Because if we could then we could do this:

```
var alimentList = (List<Aliment>)fruitList;
alimentList.Add(new Vegetable());
```

That would not create a new list - it would simply cast the list as a different type. But if we could cast the `List<Fruit>` as a `List<Aliment>` then we could add any `Aliment` to the list, including a `Vegetable`. Then we would have a `Vegetable` in our `List<Fruit>`.

That's not always obvious to us up front, but the compiler spots it right away and prevents it.

Because of that issue, if you use the code I showed above to fix the error in the constructor you're still going to run into the exact same problem. `Fruits` will still have a `List<Aliment>` property that it inherits from `Aliments`, so you could still do this:

```
var fruits = new Fruits(someListOfFruit);
fruits.AlimentList.Add(new Vegetable());
```

That wouldn't give you a compiler error, but it's still obviously not the behavior you want.

What might help you is a generic class like this:

```
public abstract class Aliments<T> where T : Aliment
{
    public Aliments(List<T> alimentList)
    {
        AlimentList = alimentList;
    }
    public List<T> AlimentList { get; private set; }
}
```

It allows you to do this. You can define a class that inherits from `Aliments` but specifies the actual type of `Aliment`.

```
public class Fruits : Aliments<Fruit>
{
    public Fruits(List<Fruit> alimentList) : base(alimentList)
    {
    }
}
```

By specifying `Fruit` for the generic parameter `T`, your `AlimentList` property is now defined as a `List<Fruit>`. The compiler will only let you add `Fruit` to it.